# PayPal not sending the transaction information on return

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to implement PayPal payments but regardless of what options or answers I've found so far, it still won't send back the transaction information to the success callback url (tx, st, amt and cc)

I've set the auto return to on, the PDT to on, tried to set rm to all the possible values (0, 1 and 2) but still no luck

The confusing part is that PayPal's documentation clearly mentions that I should be getting them in all cases except if I'm using rm 1 and am including a return url, but I just don't

> Return URL behavior. If set to “1” and if a “return” value is
>   submitted, upon completion of the payment the buyer will be sent
>   back to the return URL using a GET method, and no transaction
>   variables will be submitted. If set to “2” and if a “return” value is
>   submitted, the buyer will be sent back to the return URL using a
>   POST method, to which all available transaction variables will
>   also be posted. If omitted or set to “0”, GET methods will be used
>   for all Subscriptions transactions and Buy Now, Donations, or
>   PayPal Shopping Cart transactions in which IPN is not enabled.
>   POST methods with variables will be used for the rest

It does return to the success page, but doesn't include the transaction information (btw, even when setting the rm to 2 and having the appropriate return url, it still does a GET rather than a POST, which is why I'm suspecting that the documentation is out of date or that the sandbox env. is bugged)

For what it's worth, here are my relevant form fields

```
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-h7plu24373@business.example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="@(Url.Action("Success", "Paypal", null, "https", (string) ViewBag.host))">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="@(Url.Action("Failed", "Paypal", null, "https", (string) ViewBag.host))">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
```

[image from the sample controller i'm using to test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJWJE.png)

[Image from that business dummy account with it's settings done properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0VUO.png)

Any idea what am i missing? I've been thinking of ditching PDT altogether and rely on the IPN webhook, but I thought I would ask first

P.S. I've tested with an actual host name, live debugging but still the same scenario happened, it returns to the return url but without the transaction information, I've even checked the browser network tab to check the request to make sure it's nothing funny on my site and it's surly sending the request without the transaction information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing in the sandbox environment might be related to the problem you're having with PDT; it's possible it could just work in Live.  But a more overlooked problem with this design and use of PDT is that the return is actually never guaranteed. Depending on the buyer's locale and circumstance (for example a guest checkout), PayPal may be obligated to show the buyer a receipt, in which case the return is not automatic unless the buyer clicks the button to return. Alternatively, the buyer's browser could crash or have its network connection interrupted after the transaction completes but before the return takes place.  So, in practice, PDT is in no way reliable, and should be used for informational purposes only (e.g. to display a thank you message to the customer).  ***None* of your business logic (that is right, none) should ever rely on PDT actually working.**

Instead, you can build your design around an IPN or Webhook as you mention, although that too can be asynchronous and delayed.

---

The most robust solution would be a server-side design that captures with an API call to PayPal, and so is immediately notified of success/failure based on the response of that server-side API call. Here is a skeleton demo: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Notice that no PayPal transaction takes place until the `fetch(` XHR to a server endpoint, which then must do its own capture API call to PayPal.